# I have 2 main dbs and i want to create one as a connection of those two

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dbconnect

I have a simple project in mind.
2 apps with 2 seperate databases (sql server)

I want to have a third db that stores the information i want from
db2 (lets call it Item Info) into a table Tb1 and when there is an insert on db1 (lets call it orders) store the info of order in Tb2.

Then insert order into db2 so i can have a log of the orders for each item .

Can you provide me with some tips where to start from or an e-book that covers my case or something relative?

Comment: This feels like an flawed design. Why do you want to effectively replicate the data from 2 databases into a single one? Why are you storing the item in one database and the orders in another? That means that there can be no relationship defined between the 2; do you customer not order items?

Comment: i know its a flawed design i just want to start something "idiotic" and then move to something more complex.  App1 has items customers orders, App2 has Items-Storage
i just want to get info from app1 and insert into app2.

Comment: But why? All this data seems like it should be in one database to start with; not 3 with the data from 2 different ones replicated into a "merged" database. What "problem" are you trying to solve by this flawed design?

Comment: i have a database that keeps track of fuel in storage and fuel sales (qty per sale)
i also have an erp db 
i want to get the data (qty) for each sal and automatically insert a sales document into erp db instead of getting a print list of Today Sales and then inserting qties by hand

Comment: Why don' t you create an event trigger on the source databases and migrate that data to target database via database link. Yet, this path full of traps.